# allowing index access only with .htaccess

Tags: security, .htaccess

I have this in my .htaccess file, in the site root:

```
Options -Indexes
<directory ../.*>
Deny from all
</directory> 

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

<Files index.php>
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to block folder and file access to anything that isn't called index.php, regardless of which directory is accessed. I have the folder part working perfectly and the deny from all rule is working as well - but my attempt to allow access to index.php is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are thinking to complicated, just deny all access and then allow access to index.php and the folder itself. For example:

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from All

<FilesMatch "^(index\.php)?$">
        Allow from All
</FilesMatch>
```

If you don't even want http://doma.in/folder/ to work you can replace the FilesMatch directive with `Files index.php`. Keep in mind that it depends on your `DirectoryIndex` directive what file will be displayed when accessing a folder without filename.

**Edit:** To answer the question in your comment, I think you will need a more powerfull .htaccess using mod_rewrite. You can't use Directory and DirectoryMatch in a .htaccess file accordingly to the Apache documentation. Because the request is being denied before the RewriteRule can add a trailing slash you can't add the trailing slash with mod_write.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/index\.php$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from All
</IfModule>
```

Comment: edit: That actually works for sub-directories if I add a trailing slash. Can I set it to work without a trailing slash?

Comment: Ok, working from your example I was able to accomplish 99% of what I wanted. Thanks for helping a .htaccess beginner! If you can show me how to allow access without a trailing slash, I'd still appreciate it.